# write user-defined structure to file, in binary mode

Tags: c++, file-io

In a `c++` textbook I learn that I should be able to do this (write/read a user-defined type to a file, in binary mode):

```
struct mystruct
{
    int a;
    double b;
};

void main()
{
    struct mystruct s = {1,2.0};
    std::ofstream out("binary.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    out.write(reinterpret_cast< const char* > (&s), sizeof(struct mystruct));
}
```

The code compiles and runs but the resultant file is cannot be read by text-editors. then I use binary mode to read the file:

```
std::ifstream in("binary.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
struct mystruct t;
in.read( reinterpret_cast<char*> (&t), sizeof(struct mystruct));
```

However it turns out it's unsuccessful (it doesn't get the numbers 1 and 2.0). Maybe I interpret the textbook wrongly..., or maybe something wrong with the code?

Comment: It looks like you did not post the actual code, since you have at least one typo which would prevent the above from compiling ("bindary"). Please only post actual compilable code - use copy and paste to avoid errors.

Comment: also, this method of serializing objects is not portable.

Comment: Looks like you need some good serialization library, e.g. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/?csw=1

Comment: ok looks like this 'serialisation' is system-dependent... The textbook is hiding lots of stuff underneath.

Comment: The fact that you're writing `void main` suggests that you're not using a very good text book to learn C++ from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the resultant file is cannot be read by text-editors

That's because you didn't write *text* to the file. The data cannot be interpreted meaningfully in any character encoding. You can use `hexdump` or similar tool for a meaningful representation.

> Maybe I interpret the textbook wrongly..., or maybe something wrong with the code?

I don't think so. There's nothing wrong with the pieces of code individually except weird formatting and redundant keywords. Besides non-portability of the file of course. And the invalid return type of `main`.

However, perhaps what you did was a single program like this:

```
// ...
std::ofstream out("binary.dat", std::ios::binary);
out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&s), sizeof(s));
std::ifstream in("binary.dat", std::ios::binary);
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t), sizeof(t));
// ...
```

There's a bug here. As you can see from the documentation, `ostream::write` writes to it's associated stream buffer. It's not until `ostream::flush` is called that the buffer is written to output. So, in the above code, the file is empty at the time it is read. This can obviously be fixed by calling `out.flush()` before reading the file.

As mentioned in comments, this is not at all portable. What that means is that a file written by your program on one computer may not be readable by your program on another computer. Even on the same computer, two programs compiled with different compiler options may not have the same memory layout for the class.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do the standard way. It's simple and easy to understand

```
struct mystruct {
    int a;
    double b;

    friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & out, mystruct & mys) {
        out << mys.a << " " << mys.b << std::endl;
        return out;
    }

    friend std::istream & operator >>(std::istream & in, mystruct & mys) {
        in >> mys.a >> mys.b;
        return in;
    }
};
```

The usage will be simple now. For example

```
mystruct s;
```

To read

```
std::ifstream in("binary.dat");
in >> s;
```

To write

```
std::ofstream out("binary.dat");
out << s;
```

You can also overload `std::string` operator inside the struct if you want to serialize

```
operator std::string() const {
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << a << " " << b;
   return ss.str();
}
```